# PHP Design Pattern for using instantiated classes

Tags: php, class, oop, design-patterns, reusability

We are trying to understand the best way to use mysqli/other classes in multiple custom classes so that we don't instantiate a new object every time.

Is the code below the best/correct way of doing this?

The functions are only examples.

Thank you :)

```
<?php  
class Base {

  public function __get($name) {
    if($name == 'db'){
      $db = new mysqli('**', '*s', '*', '*');
      $this->db = $db;
      return $db;
    }

  if($name == 'blowfish'){       
    $blowfish = new PasswordHash(8, true);
    $this->blowfish = $blowfish;
    return $blowfish;
  }
  }

}

class A extends Base {

  public function validate($username, $password) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

    return $query->num_rows;
  }

  public function password($password)
  {
    return $this->blowfish->HashPassword($password);
  }

}

class PasswordHash {
  public function __construct($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes) { }

  public function HashPassword($password) {
    return $password;
  }

}

$a = new A;

echo $a->validate('test','test'); // returns number rows count as expected
echo $a->password('password123'); // returns password123 as expected
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are/should probably be more interested in [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead of creating a tight coupling of Base|A and the MySQL database.